# Tensorflow tf.reduce_min how to get the minimal value from certain indexs instead of the whole tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to learn the DQN using tensorflow. In my action spaces, I have valid and invalid actions for each state. I setup the q_target network as

```
t1 = tf.layers.dense(s_, 20, tf.nn.relu, w,b, name='t1')
q_next = tf.layers.dense(t1, n_actions, w,b, name='t2')
```

How can I make it work in tensorflow, such that

```
q_target = r + self.gamma * max(q_next(valid_actions))
```

For example:

```
q_target = [1, 2, 3;4, 5, 6], 
valid_actions = [true,true,false;false,true,false],
output: max(q_next_valid) = [2;5]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your **example** scenario.

You can try to implement this using `tf.math.reduce_max()` method.

```
import tensorflow as tf  # Tensorflow 2.1.0

q_target = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]] 
valid_actions = [[True,True,False],[False,True,False]]
valid_actions = tf.cast(valid_actions, dtype = tf.int32)

# output: max(q_next_valid) = [2;5]
tf.math.reduce_max(q_target*valid_actions, axis=1, keepdims=False) # <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([2, 5], dtype=int32)>
tf.math.reduce_max(q_target*valid_actions, axis=1, keepdims=True)  # <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 1), dtype=int32, numpy= array([[2],[5]], dtype=int32)>
```

I converted your **Boolean** into **Integer** so I can multiply it to the `q_target` that will **zero-out** wrong values. And also when you set `keepdims = True` it will retain the original Rank of the Tensor, hence when `False` it will reduce the Rank of the Tensor by 1.

You can read more about `tf.math.reduce_max()` in the documentation in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_max).